# UITableView sections are not ordered as expected

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a tableView with customised section titles. The core data objects are shown on a precise section depending on the value from a transient attribute called sectionIdentifier. Everything is working as expected, but the order of the sections is not responding as I expected. This should be the sections order:

```
1. OVERDUE, sectionIdentifier = 0
2. TODAY, sectionIdentifier = 1
3. TOMORROW, sectionIdentifier = 2
4. UPCOMING, sectionIdentifier = 3
5. SOMEDAY, sectionIdentifier = 4
```

At this app state, the section order is as shown in the image below:
[image]

Any help is welcome to explain this behaviour and to find the way to obtain the desired section order.
Here is my code to help you find the issue.

```
#import "ToDoItemsTableViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "AddToDoItemViewController.h"
#import "ToDoSubItemsTableViewController.h"

@interface ToDoItemsTableViewController ()<UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end

@implementation ToDoItemsTableViewController
@synthesize searchResults;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
    return [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]managedObjectContext];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //navigation bar background image
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar

     setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar.png"]

     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                    [UIColor whiteColor],NSBackgroundColorAttributeName,nil];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar"]];


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController]performFetch:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
        abort();
    }
    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.searchResults = nil;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"addToDoItem"]){
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;

        AddToDoItemViewController *addToDoItemViewController = (AddToDoItemViewController*)navigationController.topViewController;
        ToDoItem *addToDoItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ToDoItem" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        addToDoItem.todoDueDate = [NSDate date];
        addToDoItemViewController.addToDoItem = addToDoItem;
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toToDoSubItems"]){

        ToDoSubItemsTableViewController *todoSubItemsTableViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ToDoItem *selectedToDoItem = (ToDoItem*)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        todoSubItemsTableViewController.selectedToDoItem = selectedToDoItem;



    }




}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]count];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }
    else {
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

    }
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    ToDoItem *toDoItem = nil;



    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        if (cell==nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        }
        NSLog(@"Configuring cell to show search results");
        toDoItem = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.todoName;



        NSDate *fechaToDO = toDoItem.todoDueDate;

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY"];
        NSString *fechaToDo = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:fechaToDO];



        cell.detailTextLabel.text = fechaToDo;

    }
    else
    {


    ToDoItem *todoItem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = todoItem.todoName;



    NSDate *fechaToDO = todoItem.todoDueDate;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY"];
    NSString *fechaToDo = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:fechaToDO];



    cell.detailTextLabel.text = fechaToDo;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *header = @"customHeader";

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *vHeader;

    vHeader = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:header];

    if (!vHeader) {
        vHeader = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:header];
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    if (section == 0) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    else if (section == 1) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    else if (section == 2) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else if (section == 3) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else if (section == 4) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }


    vHeader.textLabel.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];

    return vHeader;
}
-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
        NSString *valor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S E A R C H   R E S U L T S (%d)",[self.searchResults count]];
        return valor;
    }
    else {


    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> theSection = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    NSString *sectionname = [theSection name];

    if ([sectionname isEqualToString:@"0"]){

        NSString *valor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"O V E R D U E   (%d)", [self.tableView
                                                             numberOfRowsInSection:section]];
        return valor;
    }
    else if ([sectionname isEqualToString:@"1"]){

        NSString *valor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"T O D A Y   (%d)", [self.tableView
                                           numberOfRowsInSection:section]];
        return valor;
    }
    else if ([sectionname isEqualToString:@"2"]){

        NSString *valor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"T O M O R R O W   (%d)", [self.tableView
                                                             numberOfRowsInSection:section]];
        return valor;
    }
    else if ([sectionname isEqualToString:@"3"]){

        NSString *valor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"U P C O M I N G   (%d)", [self.tableView
                                                                                 numberOfRowsInSection:section]];
        return valor;
    }

    else if ([sectionname isEqualToString:@"4"]){

        NSString *valor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S O M E D A Y    (%d)", [self.tableView
                                                                                 numberOfRowsInSection:section]];
        return valor;
    }


    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController sections]count]>0){
        id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo name];
    }
    else{
        return nil;
    }
    }

}


#pragma mark - Fetched Results Controller Section

-(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController{

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil){
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ToDoItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"todoDueDate" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"todoName" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor,sortDescriptor1, nil];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;
    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier" cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}


#pragma mark - Fetched Results Controller Delegates

-(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}

-(void) controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:{

            ToDoItem *changeToDoItem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.textLabel.text = changeToDoItem.todoName;
            NSDate *fechaToDO = changeToDoItem.todoDueDate;

            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY"];
            NSString *fechaToDo = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:fechaToDO];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = fechaToDo;
        }
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }


}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type{

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }

}






// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return NO;
}



// Override to support editing the table view.







/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

 */
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Content Filtering

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    self.searchResults = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        ToDoItem * item = evaluatedObject;
        NSString* name = item.todoName;

        //searchText having length < 3 should not be considered
        if (!!searchText && [searchText length] < 3) {
            return YES;
        }

        if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [name isEqualToString:scope])  {
            return ([name rangeOfString:searchText].location != NSNotFound);
        }
        return NO; //if nothing matches
    }]];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:@"All"];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] scope:@"All"];
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)quickAddAction:(UIButton *)sender {


    UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"Add Task" message:@"Enter the task name" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Add"];
    [alert show];
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        UITextField *todoText = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"username: %@", todoText.text);

        ToDoItem *addToDoItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ToDoItem" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        addToDoItem.todoDueDate = [NSDate date];
        NSString *todoConvertido = todoText.text;
        addToDoItem.todoName = todoConvertido;
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
}
@end
```

Comment: What is para hoy, and the data shown, what does what is displayed in the cell represent? I can see you have a date, and some para hoy name name in it?

Comment: This is only test text, the first line should be the todoItem text, the second line is the todoDueDate formatted as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you sort only based on due Date and name so the category with the oldest entry comes first.

the entries would have to be sorted based on your sectionIdentifier first

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor0 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"sectionIdentifier" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"todoDueDate" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"todoName" ascending:YES];
```

Comment: aha, nice nice, so the OP missed out the sorting descriptor for sectionIdentifier ;) nice find. hopefully it works

Comment: @OP you use those three instead of your two

Comment: I've deleted my answer for now which originally proposed another way to populate his tableView and have all his data in a nice data structure which would have guaranteed to get everything working. However your approach could possibly correct his problem with his current setup without much change required! I hope this does work for him.

Comment: Thank you @Daij-Djan, but if I use your proposal the app crashes always with following exception:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath sectionIdentifier not found in entity <NSSQLEntity ToDoItem id=2>'/ The app crashes with no core data objects too, it crashes always with or without objects

Comment: sectionIdentifier is a transient attribute and I don't know if it is possible to set a NSSortDescriptor with a transient attribute as initWithKey value.

Comment: no it isn't. you need to persist it. sorry -- but that is the solution here. That OR not using fetchedResultsController

Comment: Do you think I should open a new question with this issue or it is absolutely impossible to find a solution keeping the attribute as transient? If I persist it, the objects are not sorted into sections, and if I don't persist it , the sections are not ordered as I want.

Comment: > ?If I persist it, the objects are not sorted into sections -- sure they are. it will look like it does now.

Comment: BUT it may be easier to screw using NSFetchedResultsController. Make THAT a question and Id be happy to provide you a working sample

Comment: OK, i will open another question. Thank you.