# Warning at method definition

Tags: ios, core-data

Following method is showing me a warning, but the app is executing as expected. Please could you check the code and tell me what is wrong there? Only if this important to the app, if the warning is not dangering the app, then tell me if I could let this as it is...thank you

The warning is : `Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *' from 'NSArray *'` at the method definition.

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    self.searchResults = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) 
    {
    ToDoItem * item = evaluatedObject;
    NSString* name = item.todoName;

    //searchText having length < 3 should not be considered
    if (!!searchText && [searchText length] < 3) {
        return YES;
    }

    if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [name isEqualToString:scope])  {
        return ([name rangeOfString:searchText].location != NSNotFound);
    }
    return NO; //if nothing matches
}]];
}
```

Comment: Is `searchResults` an NSMutableArray?

Comment: What is `!!searchText` ...?

Comment: it is the text coming from a search bar controller

Comment: I wasn't asking about the variable as much as the `!!`... also, why are you trying to return `BOOL` values?  The method return type is `void`.

Comment: I am not sure, the code was giving to me by another SO expert user to me in another question I made... I though it was correct as not warning is launched.

Comment: Just because it doesn't cause a warning doesn't mean it's correct...

Comment: `if (!!searchText && ...)` is very "unconventional", but does exactly  the same as `if (searchText != nil & ...)`.

Comment: Or just `if (searchText && ...)`?  I'd probably just use `__attribute__ ((nonnull()))` though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.searchResults = [[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] 
    filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:
    ^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) mutableCopy];
```

`mutableCopy` is a method on many objects for which a `mutable` and `immutable` version exists.  In the case of things like `NSArray`, `NSString`, `NSData`, etc, calling `mutableCopy` on one of these instances will return a `mutable` version containing the same contents as the original object you called the method on.

---

For example,

```
NSArray *immutableArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo",@"bar"];
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [immutableArray mutableCopy];
```

---

However, if you don't intend for `searchResults` to be an `NSMutableArray`, you should change it's declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *searchResults
```

If you don't intend it to be mutable, it should be declared as immutable.

---

Given your claim that the warning is not effecting the performance of your app, my best guess is that the proper solution would be changing `searchResults` from `NSMutableArray` to `NSArray`.

Comment: Thank you... I will follow your proposal and also the one from Martin.

Answer (score 1):

`filteredArrayUsingPredicate` returns an *immutable* `NSArray`,
and you seem to have declared `searchResults` as `NSMutableArray`.

So either

- change the declaration of `searchResults` to `NSArray`, or
- make a `mutableCopy` before assigning it.

The proper solution depends on whether you need to modify the `searchResults` later or not.

Comment: Thank you, I will change it following your proposals. @MartinR would you also mind taking a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209540/uitableview-sections-are-not-ordered-as-expected . ?