# Core Data predicate to filter objects depending on a date attribute

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am new to Swift, and haven't found any answer to my problem.

I have a Core Data entity that has several attributes. The app should manage a to-do list of tasks. One of the attributes is a Date attribute, there I store the timeStamp when the object has to be done.

I know that the date is stored with the following format:

```
2015-05-28 18:22:08 +0000
```

In a view controller I need to count the core data objects depending on the date value for the due date and time.

The needed sections are:
- Tasks with due date today
- Tasks with due date tomorrow
- Tasks with due date after tomorrow or later
- Tasks that are overdue
- Tasks without a date

Where can I find a way to perform the needed predicates?

This is my current code, where I get the number of objects with date greater than the current date:

```
func getFetchedResultController(selectedEntity: NSString){

    let appDelegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(selectedEntity as String, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
     let date = NSDate()

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "timeStamp > %@", date)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    let sectionSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptors = [sectionSortDescriptor]
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error) {
        abort()
    }

 print(fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0)
}
```

Comment: You mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222361/order-uitableview-sections-using-a-transient-attribute, but with Swift ?

Comment: @MartinR, thank you for the research. I am developing a similar app but using Swift. In this case I am not talking of a table view. I don't know if it would be easier to store the due date using the date components instead of using a NSDate value to make it easier creating the predicates...

Comment: You talked about "sections", therefore I assumed that you want to display the data in a table view. Also a NSFetchedResultsController is almost only used together with table views.

Comment: @MartinR, thank you again. I talked about "sections" but I didn't mean table view sections. The view controller has to show buttons, one button designed to show the number of objects of each type (today tasks, tomorrow tasks, etc.). That's why I need the number of objects of each type .

Comment: Does the code above work as is for getting objects with timeStamp > date and you just need the other predicates as well?  Or does the above code not work?

Comment: @Frankie, the above code works. Now there are 9 objects with timeStamp > date, and the print function is showing "9"

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it as below.

1. Add one attribute to Entity. (sectionIdentifier which is String type)
2. set date value to Attribute"sectionIdentifier" while inserting data.
3. Add section Identifier to FRC I am posting sample snippet as below

   ```
   func getFetchedResultController(selectedEntity: NSString){

   let appDelegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
   let managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!


   let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<EntityNameHere> = EntityNameHere.fetchRequest()
       fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

       let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
       fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]


   let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: “sectionIdentifier”, cacheName: “Root”)

   aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
   self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

   var error: NSError? = nil
   if !self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error) {
       abort()
   }
   ```

   print(fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0)
   }

4.Get Section Info in one of TableView section callback.

```
 let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections! as [NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo]
 let recivedDate = sectionInfo[section].name
```

5.This will return you date sections with different dates.